# DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (null) at position 0 (n): The timezone could not be found in the database

Tags: php, datetime, joomla3.0

I upgraded to the latest Joomla version and now receive this error (so far only when accessing the user manager). I've scoured the net and have found a few solutions when a particular component was causing the issue but nothing to solve mine.

If anyone could please give me a pointer on how I should resolve this php error I'd be eternally grateful:)

Answer (score 0):

Referring to https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JHtml.html

```html
calendar(string $value, string $name, string $id, string $format = '%Y-%m-%d', mixed $attribs = null) : string
```

Should look like the below code

```html
date(string $input = 'now', string $format = null, mixed $tz = true, boolean $gregorian = false) : string
```

Remember the second data is null in the date function. Change it and check your code again.